# Gulp, vinyl-fs and error "TypeError: isStream is not a function"

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a gulp file that up until relatively recently was working fine, but has started just throwing an error. I'm unsure of the best way to debug this, and google has not been of any help, so am looking for ideas on what might be wrong.  The gulpfile has the following task defined (I've removed some other tasks to try and simplify this)

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='moveToCss' />

var gulp = require('gulp');

var paths = {
    npmSrc: "./node_modules/",
    cssTarget: "./wwwroot/css/",
};

var cssToMove = [
    paths.npmSrc + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    paths.npmSrc + '/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css',
    paths.npmSrc + '/datatables.net-select-bs/css/select.bootstrap.css'
];
gulp.task('moveToCss', function () {
    return gulp.src(cssToMove).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssTarget));
});
```

but when I run this I get the following error:

```
[13:52:27] Using gulpfile C:\MyProject\gulpfile.js
[13:52:27] Starting 'moveToCss'...
gulp : C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\vinyl\i
ndex.js:142
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp moveToCss >> result.txt 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\MyProject\...yl\index.js:142:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    if (!isBuffer(val) && !isStream(val) && !isNull(val)) {
                           ^

TypeError: isStream is not a function
    at File.Object.defineProperty.set (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modul
es\vinyl-fs\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:142:28)
    at new File (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modul
es\vinyl\index.js:27:17)
    at DestroyableTransform.createFile 
(C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:12:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node
_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\nod
e_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\
_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\readable-strea
m\lib\_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_
modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at Stream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

Can anyone suggest anything? Either ideas for what might be wrong or ideas for how to diagnose the issue...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to directly access files from the `node_modules` folder, the first thing I would try is to erase the entire `node_modules` folder and reinstall all dependencies in case you inadvertently fraked something up.

If that doesn't help the offending line is [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/blob/master/index.js#L155). `isStream` comes from the [`./lib/isStream` module](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/blob/master/lib/isStream.js) which does nothing more than export a function. How you can end up with a `TypeError: isStream is not a function` message in that context is a bit of a mystery to me.

The only thing I can think of that could be of help is to add some debugging output. In `C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\vinyl\index.js` add the following right before the offending `if` statement:

```
console.log(require('util').inspect(isStream, { showHidden: true, depth: null}));
```

That should at least tell us what type `isStream` is at the time the error is thrown.

Comment: Wow, despite the fact I had double and triple checked things like permissions, ownership, read-only status, etc on both the node_modules and destination files and folders, just deleting node_modules and redoing npm install did indeed fix my issue! argh, lol.  Thanks.